# xslt with xpath queries based on a configuration file

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to write a ìn xslt (version 1.0) transformer that translates an input xml file into another format running some xpath queries written in an xml file.
Xpath queries change based on system and type variables retreived from the inptu file. 
I did:

```
<xsl:variable name="system" select="some path in input xml" />
<xsl:variable name="type" select="some path in input xml" />
```

Once calculated system and type I'm able to retrieve my query xpath as:

```
<xsl:variable name="metadata_mapping" select="some path in config xml based on system and type" />
```

All looks ok if I print:

```
<info>
        <system>
            <xsl:value-of select="$system" />
        </system>
        <type>
            <xsl:value-of select="$type" />
        </type>
            metadata-mapping:
            <xsl:value-of select="$metadata_mapping" />
        </info>
```

When I try to evaluate $metadata_mapping as an xpath query:

```
<xsl:value-of select="${metadata_mapping}" />
```

I get the following error:

17:19:44,508 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - org.apache.xml.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Impossibile trovare la variabile con il nome {metadata_mapping}
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.apache.xml.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Impossibile trovare la variabile con il nome {metadata_mapping}
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:952)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformerHandler(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.addStylesheet(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.debugger.DebugRunner$1.addStylesheet(DebugRunner.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.debugger.DebugRunner$1.addStylesheet(DebugRunner.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.addStyleSheet(PipelineDefinition.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.configure(PipelineDefinition.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.debugger.DebugRunner.main(DebugRunner.java:359)
Caused by: org.apache.xml.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Impossibile trovare la variabile con il nome {metadata_mapping}
    at org.apache.xpath.operations.Variable.fixupVariables(Variable.java:148)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.FilterExprWalker.fixupVariables(FilterExprWalker.java:240)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.WalkingIterator.fixupVariables(WalkingIterator.java:294)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.WalkingIteratorSorted.fixupVariables(WalkingIteratorSorted.java:198)
    at org.apache.xpath.XPath.fixupVariables(XPath.java:88)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemValueOf.compose(ElemValueOf.java:183)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:361)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:366)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:366)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:366)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:366)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:366)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.recompose(StylesheetRoot.java:341)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.endDocument(StylesheetHandler.java:471)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endDocument(AbstractSAXParser.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:516)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:922)

### ... 7 more

org.apache.xml.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Impossibile trovare la variabile con il nome {metadata_mapping}
    at org.apache.xpath.operations.Variable.fixupVariables(Variable.java:148)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.FilterExprWalker.fixupVariables(FilterExprWalker.java:240)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.WalkingIterator.fixupVariables(WalkingIterator.java:294)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.WalkingIteratorSorted.fixupVariables(WalkingIteratorSorted.java:198)
    at org.apache.xpath.XPath.fixupVariables(XPath.java:88)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemValueOf.compose(ElemValueOf.java:183)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:361)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:366)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:366)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:366)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:366)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.composeTemplates(StylesheetRoot.java:366)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.recompose(StylesheetRoot.java:341)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.endDocument(StylesheetHandler.java:471)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endDocument(AbstractSAXParser.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:516)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:922)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformerHandler(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.addStylesheet(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.debugger.DebugRunner$1.addStylesheet(DebugRunner.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.debugger.DebugRunner$1.addStylesheet(DebugRunner.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.addStyleSheet(PipelineDefinition.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.configure(PipelineDefinition.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.debugger.DebugRunner.main(DebugRunner.java:359)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect `${metadata_mapping}` to do, why do you expect that to "evaluate $metadata_mapping as an xpath query"? If you use Xalan then you have support for http://xalan.apache.org/old/xalan-j/extensionslib.html#evaluate, that is an extension function to evaluate an expression as XPath. In XSLT 3 as supported by Saxon 9 there is `xsl:evaluate` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#dynamic-xpath).

Comment: Thanks, It works.

Can ypu point out why it is non working in a xsl:for-each loop?

Comment: Consider to ask a new question with the new problem precisely described with minimal but complete code snippets of XML, XSLT, result you want and result you get, so that we can reproduce the problem.